# Convert String to Date Time Format

Tags: java, time, datetime-format

I have to compare 2 dates which are in String format as: `Fri Aug 23 17:03:19 IST 2013`

I am trying to use new `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss")` to convert in `DateTime` so that dates can be comparable .

```
tempTimeStamp=Fri Aug 23 17:03:19 IST 2013
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss"); 
Date startDate;

startDate = df.parse(tempTimestamp);
String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
```

But its showing error object of this type can't be converted in DateFormat.Please help..

Comment: What is `tempTimeStamp` ? Is it `String` ?

Comment: Yes it's in String format

Answer (score 2):

You were using the wrong format to try and parse the datetime string, try using the following snippet:

```
String tempTimeStamp="Fri Aug 23 17:03:19 IST 2013"
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date startDate = startDate = df.parse(tempTimestamp);
String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
```

You can look up more on the patterns for defining the date time format at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Your expected `format` doesn't `matches` with the one provided.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your SimpleDateFormat does not match that of the String that you are using.

The input String should match `dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss`

If you are wanting simply to format the output of a Date, then no parsing of a String is necessary.